# how are you supposed to properly deal with "unknown" types?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular app, and am passing some data to a route:

```
router.navigate(['somewhere'], { state: { lol: 'lmao' } });
```

then I am trying to make use of that in a component:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
...

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(
  private location: Location
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  const lol = this.location.getState().lol;
  // do something...
}
```

And I get:
`error TS2339: Property 'lol' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`

Is there another way to handle this without casting like this?

```
interface LolState {
  lol: string;
}
ngOnInit(): void {
  const lol = (this.location.getState() as LolState).lol;
  // do something...
}
```

Once upon a time I was told "casting is bad."  So I am very curious how something like this is supposed to be dealt with........  (holding back my anger and frustration with typescript).

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the `unknown` type is to tell typescript "This could be anything, and i want you to force me to do the work to figure out what it is before i use it". So the safe way to handle an unknown is to add enough code to narrow down what you're dealing with:

```
const state = this.location.getState();
if (state && typeof state === 'object' && 'lol' in state && typeof state.lol === 'string') {
  const lol = state.lol
  // do something ...
}
```

All these checks are admittedly tedious, but that's how `unknown` was deliberately designed. It's goal is typesafety, not convenience.

If you're confidant that the state could only possibly be a `LolState`, then you could use a type assertion. As you seem to be aware, this comes with risks, since a type assertion is just a way to tell typescript "i know better than you, so don't check my work here". If you use a type assertion mistakenly, typescript can't point it out to you.

```
const state = this.location.getState() as LolState;
const lol = state.lol
// do something ...
```

You can also do something in between, where you're going to do some basic checks, but once those pass, then you're satisfied that it's a LolState:

```
const state = this.location.getState();
if (state && typeof state === 'object') {
  const lol = (state as LolState).lol
  // do something ...
}
```

Which approach to take just depends on how much knowledge you have that typescript lacks, and what level of type unsafety you're willing to accept.

Comment: This can be made a bit less painful if you use [a custom typeguard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), rather than doing the type narrowing in a lengthy condition like that. But of course you still need to write the same type checking code if you want to do this with proper type safety, it's just in a function instead.